# sqlite python3 - поиск в базе, как исправить TypeError

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Коллеги создаю базу, прописываю класс - который будет выполнять разные манипуляции с базой: ввод данных, поиск по базе. Возникла трудность в реализации поиска по столбцу и заданной переменной, нужна ваша помощь:

```
   import sqlite3
   conn = sqlite3.connect('myjob.db')
   c = conn.cursor()
   #создаем таблицы в базе
   # c.execute("""CREATE TABLE employees (
   #             first text,
   #             last text,
   #             pay integer
   #             )""")
   # conn.commit()
   # conn.close()

   #создаем класс по поиску в базе данных
   class Employee:

       def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
           self.first = first
           self.last = last
           self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
           self.pay = pay

       def fullname(self):
           return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

       #Наполняем базу данными по пользователям
       def add_database(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with conn:
               c.execute("INSERT INTO employees (first, last, pay) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (self.first, self.last, self.pay))

       #поиск по столбцу например LAST и заданной переменной
      def find_lastname_database(self, lastname):
           with conn:
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last=?", (lastname,))
           return c.fetchall()

   emp_4 = Employee('Коля', 'Иванов', 75000)
   Employee.add_database(emp_4)
   emps = Employee.find_lastname_database('Иванов')
   print(emps)
```

Возникает ошибка вида:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "users.py", line 66, in <module>
    emps = Employee.find_lastname_database('Иванов')
TypeError: find_lastname_database() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lastname'
```

Подскажите почему Отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент когда задан lastname? что нужно поправить в коде, что бы выводились данные из базы по заданному столбцу и переменной при передаче параметра в функцию find_lastname_database?

Comment: спасибо, скорректировал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что метод `find_lastname_database` вызывается как статичный (`Employee.find_lastname_database('Иванов')`), но им не является подправьте:

```
@staticmethod
def find_lastname_database(lastname):
     with conn:
          c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last=?", (lastname,))

     return c.fetchall()
```

Описание метода `def find_lastname_database(self, lastname):` говорит что ожидается 2 параметра: `self` и `lastname`. Для методов класса, в `self` автоматически подставляется ссылка на текущий объект, который метод и вызвал. Но т.к. метод вызывался статично, то значение `'Иванов'` попало в `self`, а второй параметр оказался незаполненным.

---

Вот наглядный пример подстановки `self`:

```
class Foo:
    def get_self(self):
        return self


f = Foo()
print(f)             # <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000000001E458D0>
print(f.get_self())  # <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000000001E458D0>
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что если без статик метода то нужно вызов делать по другом: и тогда будет выглядеть так:
def find_lastname_database(self):
     with conn:
          c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last=?", (lastname,))

     return c.fetchall()

emps = Employee.find_lastname_database('Иванов')
print(emps)

Comment: Не, без статики, метод будет вызывать у объекта Employee: `emp = Employee('1', '2', '3')` `emps = emp.find_lastname_database('Иванов')`. Когда вы пишите `<Название Класса>()`, вызывается конструктор `__init__` и после этого создается объект